# Go言語でGOPATHを複数作りたい

Tags: go, コマンドプロンプト

Go言語でGOPATHをデフォルトのC:\Users\user\goに現在設定しているのですが、GOPATHを増やしたいと考えています。
「環境変数」から追加も調べても方法が理解できず、試していません。
setをつかっても環境変数が変わるだけで追加にはなりません。どうしたらよいでしょうか

環境は
・windows10
・コマンドプロンプト
です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: [Can I have multiple GOPATH directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36017866)

Comment: Thank you. I solved this question by this comment.

Comment: もし問題が解決した場合は、[解決した方法や手順を具体的に回答として投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowsの場合は環境変数の設定で
GOPATHの続きに「;」を加え、追加したいPathを記述することでGOPATHが追加できた。

[image: GOPATHの追加方法(Windows)]